# Comparing two columns in different Excel spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have two Excel spreadsheets. In the first spreadsheet I have two columns. Column A has 240 Accounts entries and Column B has Values for each account entry. Once again Spreadsheet 2 has its data in the same form.

What I want to achieve:

Compare each column's entry of Spreadsheet 2 against Spreadsheet 1.

Say Spreadsheet 2 column has 4 entries like 111,222,333,444 and suppose I want to validate the value for entry 111. Then my formula should search for 111 in Spreadsheet 1 Column A, then it should pick the value for it, then compare it with the value of the Spreadsheet 2 Column B entry for 111, and give me the difference.

Answer (score 3):

use a VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A2:$B$240,2,FALSE)
```

Put this in every row on sheet 1 where there is a row of data, in a blank column next to the data. It would look at the ID in that row, look for that ID in sheet 2, then return the value it finds.

```
=VLOOKUP(AdjacentCellWithID,TargetTable,NumberOfColumnsAcrossFromLeft,FALSE)
```

I would also recommend you use tables, this way you can dynamically refer to the ranges, meaning less work in future to keep the function working:

```
=VLOOKUP([@[ID]],[ValuesTable],2,FALSE)
```

This should be useful: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/03/30/comprehensive-guide-excel-vlookup/

***And finally:***

Looking at your last line, you want to find the difference between the two values?

So you could do this:

```
=[@[Value]-VLOOKUP([@[ID]],[ValuesTable],2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=$B2-VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A2:$B$240,2,FALSE)
```

Without knowing more about your data I can't be sure if the two values are the right way around.

Comment: Nice answer @ClockeWork. Did the questioner even return to SU to check his answer? If not what is the point in taking out one's time to give answers for such questioners?

Comment: Thanks @Prasanna. It's a shame if they didn't come back, but if the answer helps *anyone* then it's worth the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a difference of vlookups.  Assuming your desired comparison value is in cell E2, you could use

=VLOOKUP(E2,Sheet1!A:B,2,0)-VLOOKUP(E2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)

See below:

[image]